# Apache Tika: Convert Apache Tika server REST endpoints(Jax-Rs) http to https

Tags: java, ssl, jax-rs, apache-tika, tika-server

We use Apache Tika to extract data from files(multiple formats). We call Tika server Rest endpoints internally from the .Net code to do the data extraction process. We are trying to research and see if we can add SSL/TLS support to the Tika server REST endpoints. ANy help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You'll probably get the best responses by asking on our user/dev lists (https://tika.apache.org/mail-lists.html) or opening a "wish" issue on our JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TIKA)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is requesting this I've raised a jira and added some comments to show it's possible, it's currently being worked through.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3719

Comment: This is now part of tika server (beta):
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-SSL(Beta)